# Pandas: reshaping a dataframe with duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a Pandas DF (brief snippet below) called `df`

```
    deathtype    height    deaths
0   AMS           4900       1
1   AMS           5150       1
2   AMS           5300       1
3   Avalanche     5350       14
4   Avalanche     5600       4
5   Avalanche     5700       1
6   Avalanche     5800       17
7   Unexplained   8500       1
8   Unexplained   8560       1
```

I'm trying to reshape the data into the following;

```
deaths         1                4          14       17
deathtype               
AMS           4900,5150,5300    0          0        0
Avalanche     5700              5600       5350     5800
Unexplained   8500, 8560        0          0        0
```

I know that a pivot_table can't achieve this since the aggfunc uses the mean for duplicate values which means that for all the `deaths` values of 1, the mean will be recorded. A pivot_table gives me the following;

```
df.pivot_table(index='deathtype', columns='deaths', values='height', fill_value='0')

deaths           1              4      14     17
deathtype               
AMS           5116.666667       0      0      0
Avalanche     5700.000000       5600   5350   5800
Unexplained   8530.000000       0      0      0
```

I'm looking for some advice on how to go about doing this. It looks like a pivot_table isn't the right approach here. Can someone please provide some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` with aggregate by `join`, then reshape by `unstack`:

```
d = lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))
df = df.groupby(['deathtype', 'deaths'])['height'].agg(d).unstack(fill_value='0')
print (df)
deaths                     1     4     14    17
deathtype                                      
AMS          4900, 5150, 5300     0     0     0
Avalanche                5700  5600  5350  5800
Unexplained        8500, 8560     0     0     0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(['deathtype', 'deaths'])['height'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))))
deathtype    deaths
AMS          1         4900, 5150, 5300
Avalanche    1                     5700
             4                     5600
             14                    5350
             17                    5800
Unexplained  1               8500, 8560
Name: height, dtype: object
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='deathtype', 
                    columns='deaths', 
                    values='height', 
                    fill_value='0', 
                    aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str)))
```

Comment: jezrael - thanks a lot for showing the two ways of doing this. This was exactly what I needed.